# Is there file scope in bash programming?

Tags: bash

I want to make this variable

```
    local to="$HOME/root_install/grunt"
```

be available to the entire file

```
makeGrunt(){

    # set paths
    local to="$HOME/root_install/grunt"
    cd $to

    sudo npm install -g grunt-init
    sudo git clone https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-gruntfile.git ~/.grunt-init/gruntfile
    sudo grunt-init gruntfile
}
```

Comment: Simply drop the `local` keyword

Comment: As an aside: Make it `cd "$to" || return` so that your script doesn't run `npm install` in some unknown directory should your `cd` fail. (http://shellcheck.net/ will give you like advice re: the need to test for success of `cd`).

Answer (score 2):

In **POSIX-like shells** - unless you use *nonstandard* constructs such as `local`, `typeset`, or `declare` - **variables created *implicitly* through 
*assignment* have *global* scope in the shell at hand.**

Thus, `to="$HOME/root_install/grunt"` will make variable `$to` available *anywhere* in the current shell - unless you're inside a function and that variable was *explicitly* marked as *local*.

[andlrc's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40368889/45375) demonstrates the **pitfalls associated with *subshells*** - subshells are *child* processes that are *clones* of the original shell - they see the same state, but *cannot modify the original shell's environment*.

Answer (score 1):

Bash shells use [dynamic
scopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping)
which means that all variables are available for all called functions, commands,
etc. Consider this:

```
var=1
a() {
    local var=2
    b
}
b() {
    echo "$var"
}
a # 2
b # 1
a # 2
```

When using the `local` keyword a variable will be available for the function, in
where it's defined, but also within all functions called from that function.

The same applies when a variable is created without the `local` keyword. With
that exception that it will also be available outside the function.

One more thing to be aware of is that whenever a subshell is created a variable
will not be able to "leave" it, i.e. when a pipe is involved. Consider this:

```
sum=0
seq 3 | while read -r num; do
  sum=$((sum + num))
  echo "$sum" # will print 1, 3 and 6
done
echo "$sum" # 0 huh? 1 + 2 + 3 = 0?
```